# Authenticate client-side app with Google Cloud Platform

Tags: authentication, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, auth0

I am currently developing a client-side app where users login using e-mail/password against MongoDB Atlas. The backend runs completely serverless.

All logged in users should be able to upload and retrieve images from GCP - Storage bucket without a visible login, which means the application should authenticate for every user on the background.

I was thinking about using Google Service Accounts in combination with [auth0](https://auth0.com/), but I don't know where to start...

If someone could help me tell where to start, that would be great :)

Answer (score 0):

The question is difficult to answer. However, here some insights.

The prefered way is to have a serverless backend, [AppEngine standard](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/), [Cloud Run](https://cloud.google.com/run/) or [Cloud Function](https://cloud.google.com/functions) for doing this. The user performs its authentication and then exchange security token between the frontend and the backend. When the user want to reach a GCP resource, it asks the backend, which request the request thanks to its own service account.

By the way, it's easy to trace the user request and to serve him only the resources related to it. And you have only 1 service account, for the backend

If you grant access to a bucket to a user, it could download all the files (But maybe there is one bucket per user?). If you chose to limit object access with ACL, the management is complex.

You don't need to have a service account per user (and in any case, you have a [quota to 100 service accounts per project](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/service-accounts#user-managed_service_accounts)), you can use [Cloud Identity Platform (CIP)](https://cloud.google.com/identity-platform/) instead of your MongoDB database for authentication (CIP don't perform authorization, you should use MongoDB for authorization and other stuffs related to authenticated user). *CIP is Firebase Auth rebranded*